# facebook login in a website - why facebook app?

Tags: python, html, django, facebook, facebook-login

i am reading the docs for logging into a website using facebook account.

the steps in this doc are:
1) create facebook app
2) other steps to setup the login.

but what i dont understand is: why do i need to create an app in facebook?. my thought was simply: ask the user to login into his facebook account -> get him autherised -> and login him into webpage. why do i need this extra facebook app? if the user sees this facebook app, he is scared to login since this app isnot known to him.

Comment: When you make an app you get some credentials with facebook. Then that user can grant you (your app) rights to view their data, post for them, etc. whatever you request. How would Facebook tie the user to your application unless there was some id in Facebook to tie your application to the user... ie the Facebook App. App is sort of incorrect in your instance, but it is still what it is. Just don't request more access than you need and users won't be scraed.

Comment: @Leeish, so i need to create an app in order to implement the login process, right?

Comment: Yes. As far as I know that is the only way.

Comment: @Leeish, look. do i have to be registered developer in facebook to create this app? can you pls tell me how to create this app? :(

Comment: I don't remember if you have to register. I think its just tied to your Facebook account. http://developers.facebook.com/ you should just use your facebook login. Read the documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/ is all the documentation on the Facebook login. I've used it before, it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Leeish, very nice. thanks thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26129/discussion-between-doniyor-and-leeish)

Comment: The question is: what **won't** scare a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our chat discussion, this page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

Holds all the answers anyone with FBLogin questions are looking for as far as javascript authentication.

Comment: wonderful!. very nice help, thanks

Comment: working like a charm now.